# total charactors per screen for windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, pivot

i'm trying to build a book-like reader without any scrolling down option per page, therefore, the only solution i've found that is to use dynamic pivot control to hold up large amount text
my question is: for different windows phone, different resolution, how do I set the total amount of characters for each page in order to avoid the scrolling down? or in another word, auto wrapping per page when the text reaches the screen end?

Comment: Just set the size of the list box to the size of the screen in the XAML designer

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 supported resulution. wxvga, xvga, 720P (and 1080P). Just test all with the emulator.